# Restrict routes by environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

We (me and all my personalities, of course) have several routes we'd like to not expose in production but we use in development and testing. I know you can (or could?) add a before filter in the controller to lock down these things depending upon environment, but can this be done from config/routes.rb?

thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
if Rails.env.development?
   resources :secrets
end
```

As I understand the router, that should work.

Comment: could it be THAT easy? I love this rails thing!

Comment: It's pretty great, isn't it :)

Comment: it could be easier: `resources :secrets if Rails.env.development?`

Comment: True, but he did say "routes" as in more than one, so I imagine if there are several of these the conditional block will look nicer. If it's only one you're spot on of course.

Comment: yeah, we have several to put together. This is all good stuff and I feel much gratitude :)